# AWS SAM - How to pass parameters to Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am trying to pass Parameter values when executing `sam deploy`. For example:

```
sam package \
    --template-file lambda.yaml \
    --s3-bucket myexamplebucket \
    --output-template-file packaged.yaml

sam deploy --template-file ./packaged.yaml \
    --stack-name stack-test-lambda \
    --parameter-overrides ${lambda_param} \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

However, I get: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [LambdaRoleARN] must have values.`

`lambda_param` contains: "LambdaRoleARN"="arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-lambda-role"

Do I need to pass parameters in a different way? Currently the Code Uri is just pointing to the 'lambda_example.py' file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  LambdaRoleARN:
    Type: String

Resources:
  LambdaS3EventResponse: 
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda-s3-event-response
      Role: !Ref LambdaRoleARN
      Handler: lambda_example.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 300
      CodeUri: ../../lambda/src/helpers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. The `"` was not being passed correctly in Bash script. By passing the command into an array and executing as below ensured the `"` was correctly passed.

```
array=(
sam deploy --template-file ./packaged.yaml \
    --stack-name stack-test-lambda \
    --parameter-overrides ${lambda_param} \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
)
eval $(echo ${array[@]})
```